# How to make pagination of inbook lowercase

Tags: biblatex

A page range given in `@inbook` results in "Pp." (uppercase) compared to "pp." (lowercase) for `@article` when using `block=npar`. What has to be done to have it in lowercase as well?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[block=nbpar]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@article{foo,
      author         = "Foo Bar",
      title          = "Baz",
      journal        = "A. B. C.",
      volume         = "1",
      issue          = "2",
      pages          = "100-200",
}

@inbook{bar,
      author         = "Foo Bar",
      booktitle      = "Qux",
      title          = "Baz",
      pages          = "100-200",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: outcome of MWE]

Comment: Make a complete example. Such words depend on language and style.

Comment: I don't get uppercase page ranges with `@inbook`, so please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Localization strings are capitalized following terminal or sentence-ending punctuation characters specified by `\DeclareCapitalPunctuation`. By default:

```
\DeclareCapitalPunctuation{.!?}
```

The manual's description of this command also mentions that strings at the beginning of paragraphs (e.g. after `\par`) are also capitalized. To avoid this in paragraph-ending blocks you can modify the `\newblockpunct` command. For example the following

```
\newtoggle{blockterm}
\preto{\newblockpunct}{\ifterm{\toggletrue{blockterm}}{\togglefalse{blockterm}}}
\appto{\newblockpunct}{\iftoggle{blockterm}{}{\midsentence}}
```

Will suppress capitalization at the beginning of a new block unless preceded by one of the characters specified in `\DeclareCapitalPunctuation`.