# Insert newline before pages, no double newline for inbook

Tags: biblatex

Following up on,
[How to make pagination of inbook lowercase](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112743/how-to-make-pagination-of-inbook-lowercase). How do I insert a newline before the pages field?

I tried

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\newline\mkpageprefix[pagination]{#1}}
```

but for `@inbook` it results in one newlines too much. Probably the real question is: How to turn "pages" into a block, so it is "newlined" by `block=npar` automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[block=nbpar]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@article{foo,
      author         = "Foo Bar",
      title          = "Baz",
      journal        = "A. B. C.",
      volume         = "1",
      issue          = "2",
      pages          = "100-200",
}

@inbook{bar,
      author         = "Foo Bar",
      booktitle      = "Qux",
      title          = "Baz",
      pages          = "100-200",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\newtoggle{blockterm}
\preto{\newblockpunct}{\ifterm{\toggletrue{blockterm}}{\togglefalse{blockterm}}}
\appto{\newblockpunct}{\iftoggle{blockterm}{}{\midsentence}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\newline\mkpageprefix[pagination]{#1}}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is that the `article` driver doesn't include a new block before `pages`, whereas `inbook` does, as you have correctly surmised.

Remove your alteration to the pages field format, and include the following in your preamble to change the `article` driver. I'm afraid I'm not sufficiently au fait with the patching commands to work out how to place such a patch in the middle of the driver, so although all we are doing is adding one command, I've had to give you the entire driver. The line being changed is marked with a comment.

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock% <--- THIS LINE CHANGED HERE
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{issn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{related}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

Comment: `\usepackage{xpatch}` and `\xpatchbibdriver{article}{\usebibmacro{note+pages}}{\newblock\usebibmacro{note+pages}}{}{}` would do the equivalent. To consistently insert a new block before the `pages` field, one can use `\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcomma\newblock}`.

Comment: @Audrey The patching answer is more sensible for the average user than mine. Perhaps you could make it an answer? (But I can't find hacking a punctuation macro so that it adds a block to be anything less than unnatural!)

Comment: I prefer to avoid multiple answers, especially when the approach is basically the same. The redefinition `\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcomma\par\nobreak}` would be more "natural", but I already have the OP using a patched version of `\newblockpunct`.